# Where is the serial number located on the Yongnuo YN-568EX II?

Tags: yongnuo, serial-number

I've recently bought a couple of Yongnuo YN-568EX II flashguns and to register my equipment on lenstag I need to photograph the serial number. The problem is that I can't find it. I've searched the internet but found nothing. Several other Yongnuo flashes are registered by other people at lenstag and I've found reports about a stolen [Yongnuo YN-568EX](https://www.lenstag.com/stolen/YN13491316--Yongnuo-YN568EX-.html) that was registered their too. It seems strange if they removed the serial number from the mark II version.

Where can I find the serial number on the Yongnuo YN-568EX II?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's like my YN-568 (Mk I), adjust the tilt so the flash is "flat", then on the "bottom" side of the head, below the MADE IN CHINA plate, look in the groove right above the tilt joint. It's lightly etched, so it's easy to miss, and you're probably gonna need some side lighting to photograph it.

If you rotate the head and look at the top of the body, you'll also see the manufacture date sticker that tells you the month and year it was made.

Comment: Sure enough it was there! A very subtle serial number indeed.

Comment: @Hugo I knew where to look, because my 580EX's SN is etched just above the groove. :)

Comment: Of course, why not put the serial at the same spot too:)